# FindViewById gives error

Tags: android

I don't understand why this code is giving error as soon as I type the line 
EditText input=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
Blank activity Hello World works just fine!

here is java code.....

```
package com.example.abhishektiwari.deletethis;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
EditText input=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
}
```

And here is the xml code..

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"    android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:orientation="vertical">


<EditText
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:hint="Type the mathematical expression here"
    />
<Button
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:text="Get SVG"
    android:id="@+id/button"

    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Result"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    />
```

Comment: call findViewById after setting the view first in which that id exists

Comment: You have to create your views in OnCreate method.

Comment: just edited your post ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
EditText input=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
```

To

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    EditText input=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
}
```

Since you can not access a view outside of a member function.

Comment: If this answer was useful to you, please tick it as accepted answer :-) @user3590660

Answer (score 1):

Edit your activity

```
 public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    EditText input=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    }
    }
```

You can not access a view outside of a member function.

Answer (score 1):

it is because you declared and initialized your `EditText` outside the scope of a method, when the context is still null. Move this line

```
 EditText input=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
```

inside `onCreate`, after `setContentView`

Answer (score 1):

Use it in onCreate or just create a method and put this in that and call the function in onCreate.

```
EditText input=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call activity methods such as `findViewById()` before `onCreate()` in the activity lifecycle. Member variable initialization is too early. Move the initialization to `onCreate()` after `setContentView()`.